# Error and crash while using using UIDatePicker on Mac, Swift, Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I have a date picker in my app and it was working fine up until I updated to the latest Xcode.

Now when I use it it crashes and gives this error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIDatePickerMacCompactView _setTextColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11135ae50'

This is an app that is on iOS and Mac OS using catalyst.

The date picker works fine on the iOS devices but crashed like this on the Mac version.

Has anyone got any idea on what may be happening, I cannot find the  UIDatePickerMacCompactView in there files anywhere.

Comment: Did you find any solution about this, I am trying to release an objective-c project and the same error crashing my app

Comment: @Fisfej, yes in the end I muted all code that had set text colour and I started to use a date picker controller, if you want me to share the code for the date picker controller I can. It now, rather than pop up at the bottom it has a floating picker. I think the issue seems to arise if you use a third part date picker also such as action sheet picker 3

Answer (score 0):

Just by reading the error message, are you setting the text color as `UIColor` instead of `NSColor` by chance. I have little experience with Catalyst so I might be wrong but that's my 2 cents.

Comment: I don't set the UIdatepicker that is a part of UIkit